# Meaning of "over at"

Tags: meaning, word-usage

What does "over at" mean? I saw this being used in "A over at the site/blog/forum B". I understand this means A is somehow related to B, but I want to know the precise meaning. Does it imply that A is always at B, or A is an owner of or affiliated with B?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the phrase is, for example, "the article over at *Buz & Skup's .Net C#* blog," then *over at* has the same meaning it has in "I think the kids are over at Pam’s place." In both the cases, *over at* means *in or at a place*, and in the first case it is used similarly to *on* in *on Internet*.

Comment: Thanks! Can this also apply to people at the blog? E.g., can I say "Pam over at Buz & Skup's blog told me about this" when Pam is not regular at the blog but just happened to be at that blog and told me something?

Comment: @timur I don't think there would be any difference between a regular user and a user that visit a blog at random times, but I imagine you can say "Pam over at _Buz & Skup's_ blog" to specify that is not another user with the same username on a different blog, and that is the blog where Pam left a post directed to you.